# Rethrowing exceptions in Java without losing the stack trace

Tags: java, exception

In C#, I can use the `throw;` statement to rethrow an exception while preserving the stack trace:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   if (e is FooException)
     throw;
}
```

Is there something like this in Java (**that doesn't lose the original stack trace**)?

Comment: Why do you think it looses the original stacktrace? The only way to loose it  when you throw new SomeOtherException and forget to assign the root cause in the constructor or in initCause().

Comment: I believe this is how the code behaves in .Net, but I'm no longer positive. It might be worthwhile to either look it up somewhere or run a small test.

Comment: `Throwable`s don't get modified by throwing them. To update the stack trace you have to call `fillInStackTrace()`. Conveniently this method gets called in the constructor of a `Throwable`.

Comment: In C#, yes, `throw e;` will lose the stacktrace.  But not in Java.

Comment: Some doc from Oracle about exceptions with Java 7 : [Catching Multiple Exception Types and Rethrowing Exceptions with Improved Type Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Answer (score 683, accepted):

```
catch (WhateverException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

will simply rethrow the exception you've caught (obviously the surrounding method has to permit this via its signature etc.). The exception will maintain the original stack trace.

Comment: Hi, InterruptedException e gives an unhandled Exception message when I add the throw e line. Not so if I replace it with the broader Exception e. How should this be done properly?

Comment: @James, I just observed that the message goes away if adding "throws XxxException" in function declaration.

Comment: In Java 7 compiler for such rethrow is more inteligent. Now it works fine with specific "throws" exceptions in containing method.

Comment: @James If you `catch(Exception e) { throw e; }` that will be unhandled. If you `catch(InterruptedException ie) { throw ie; }` it will be handled. As a rule of thumb, don't `catch(Exception e)` - this isn't pokemon, and we don't want to catch 'em all!

Comment: I see some code like this in a java project I'm working on - is it a no-op and safe to delete?

Comment: @JonnyLeeds If that is a try-with-resources statement, you should not delete it.

Comment: @corsiKa It's not necessarily true that you don't want to "Catch 'em all", it's just a different use case.  If you have a top-level loop or event handler (for instance, inside a thread's run) if you don't catch at least RuntimeException and log it, you will often miss the exception altogether AND silently break out of an important loop for what is often a one-time failure.  It's also really good for plugin functionality where you don't know what additional code might do or throw...  For top-down uses like these catching Exception is often not only a good idea but a best practice.

Comment: @BillK Um, sure. But that top level loop will really be handled by a high level framework, usually. Your typical developer will rarely be writing at that kind of level and if they are, they know when rules of thumbs need to be ignored.

Comment: @CorsiKa I mentioned it because the app I work on had a few threads that were randomly eating exceptions.  Any thread you don't want to break out of silently should have a catch Exception at the top, and you might want to consider that there are a lot of developers who aren't in your exact situation--many programmers work with threads, not all use frameworks to abstract them--and some write their own frameworks.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that it may not be "obvious" to someone learning Java that the surrounding method must permit re-throwing the exception. `surroundingMethod() throws WhateverException { ... }`

Answer (score 91):

You can also wrap the exception in another one AND keep the original stack trace by passing in the Exception as a Throwable as the cause parameter:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     throw new YourOwnException(e);
}
```

Comment: I would also advise on adding a message alongside, using `throw new YourOwnException("Error while trying to ....", e);`

Comment: this is what I was looking for, especially the version from the first comment where you can pass your own message

Comment: This show the error message correctly but the stack trace shows the error line as line with 'throw new.......(e)' not the original line that caused exception.

Comment: This only works if `YourOwnException` is properly set up, see the 4 public constructors on `RuntimeException` which call `super`.

Answer (score 88):

I would prefer:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (FooException fe){
   throw fe;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Note: don't catch all exceptions like this unless you know what you
    // are doing.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Definitely proper in Java to catch specific exceptions than generic and checking for instance of. +1

Comment: And lets hope FooException is unchecked or is declared in the enclosing method's throws part. C# exceptions are unchecked and can be re-thrown freely

Comment: -1 because you should never catch plain "Exception" unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Stroboskop: true, but to answer it's best to use the same (similar) code as in the question!

Comment: In this case, yes. However, sometimes, you can recover from a custom exception only if the attributes of the (custom) exception have some "recoverable" values, hence the interest of the above form.

Comment: Sometimes catching all exceptions is ok. Such as when you are writing a test case. Or for logging purposes. Or in the main where not catching means crashing.

Comment: @JohnHenckel and others: Valid points inded. I updated the question to make it clear that catching `Exception` is typically not the right thing to do, in _most_ (but not all) cases.

Answer (score 21):

In Java is almost the same:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   if (e instanceof FooException)
     throw e;
}
```

Comment: I would add a specific catch for FooException

Comment: In this specific case I agree, but adding a specific catch may not be the right choice - imagine you have some common code for all exceptions and after, for a particular exception, rethrow it.

Comment: @MarkusLausberg But finally doesn't catch exceptions.

Comment: Yes, but this was not the question.

Comment: As you mention in the comment, this code would only make sense if you have more code that uses `e` after the if. Otherwise, it's just not quite right to use `instanceof`. You could add an ellipsis or comment stating that.

Answer (score 15):

In Java, you just throw the exception you caught, so `throw e` rather than just `throw`. Java maintains the stack trace.

Answer (score 7):

Stack trace is prserved if you wrap the catched excetion into an other exception (to provide more info) or if you just rethrow the catched excetion.

`try{
    ...
}catch (FooException e){
     throw new BarException("Some usefull info", e);
}`

Answer (score 6):

something like this

```
try 
{
  ...
}
catch (FooException e) 
{
  throw e;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public int read(byte[] a) throws IOException {
    try {
        return in.read(a);
    } catch (final Throwable t) {
        /* can do something here, like  in=null;  */
        throw t;
    }
}
```

This is a concrete example where the method throws an `IOException`. The `final` means `t` can only hold an exception thrown from the try block. Additional reading material can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21386753) and [here](http://www.javac.info/Rethrown.html).

Comment: It doesn't have to be final. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6889301/131160

Answer (score 3):

I was just having a similar situation in which my code potentially throws a number of different exceptions that I just wanted to rethrow. The solution described above was not working for me, because Eclipse told me that `throw e;` leads to an unhandeled exception, so I just did this:

```
try
{
...
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException e) {                    
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
}
```

Worked for me....:)

Comment: Avoid self-made extraction of info about `e`. Better pack the original exception with `throw new RuntimeException("Some usefull info", e)`. In the string, gives somes usefull info that are missing in `e`, for example some important arguments of your method, info about the context, or whatever will help debugging.

Comment: Please don't do this : 1. You are packing checked exception in RuntimeExceptions. 2. You are loosing informations