# Java 7 - Precise rethrow with a final Exception

Tags: java, exception, final, java-7

In previous versions of java, rethrowing an exception was treated as throwing the type of the catch parameter.

For example:

```
public static void test() throws Exception{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        df.parse("x20110731");
        new FileReader("file.txt").read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

In Java 7, you can be more precise about the exception being thrown, if you declare the exception `final`:

```
//(doesn't compile in Java<7)
public static void test2() throws ParseException, IOException{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        df.parse("x20110731");
        new FileReader("file.txt").read();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**My question**: The docs say that I need to declare the Exception `final`. But if I don't, the code above still compiles and works. Am I missing something?

**References:**

[Project Coin: multi-catch and final rethrow](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_multi_catch_rethrow) 
[Add more flexible checking for rethrown exceptions](http://www.javac.info/Rethrown.html)

Comment: The exception parameter in the catch is implicitly final. You don't need to explicitly state it as final. You can, obviously, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I *believe* I saw a tweet from Josh Bloch saying that the "final" restriction had been lifted late on. I'll see if I can find a post about it, but I suspect it's just that any "early" documentation you read is now inaccurate.

EDIT: I can't find the exact "it's changed" post, but the [Java 7 documentation states](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) shows an example with it *not* being final. It talks about exception variables being *implicitly* final when a catch block declares more than one type, but that's slightly separate.

EDIT: I've now found the source of my confusion, but it's an internal mailing list post :( Anyway, it doesn't have to be declared as final, but I believe the compiler treats it as *implicitly* final - just like in the multi-catch scenario.

Comment: Hey @jon-skeet , I know it's a +1y old post, but one thing on that last edit: in this scenario, if `e` is not declared `final`, the compiler **won't** _implicitly_ treat it as `final` (as in multi catch). However, if the `e` reference is changed, then `Exception` has to be included in the `throws` clause.

Comment: @betomontejo BullsEye.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why both compile is that an exception in a uni catch clause that is not subsequently modified is implicitly final ([JLS 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20-620)).

So for your example not to compile, you need to modify e in some way, for example:

```
public static void test2() throws ParseException, IOException {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        df.parse("x20110731");
        new FileReader("file.txt").read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ParseException) {
            e = new ParseException("Better message", 0);
        } else {
            e = new IOException("Better message");
        }
        System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
        throw e; //does not compile any more
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051791/is-there-ever-a-reason-to-not-use-the-final-keyword-when-catching-an-exception/12051907#12051907

Answer (score 0):

Without the final it is still valid java. You just lose the benefit of it being 'precise'.

Comment: I think you are missing the thrown exceptions bit of test2() - it *IS* more precise, so a "throw Exception" would normally fail.