# Precise rethrow exception in java7

Tags: java-7

assylias explain well about [final rethrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051907/4652536).
I added final to `method3`.

```
public void method4() throws IOException {
    try {
        throw new IOException("1");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e = new IOException("2"); //does not compile
        throw e; //does not compile
    }
}
```

I set my compiler to 1.7. `method4` have two compile errors :

```
final exception can neither be reassigned nor throw precise exception.
```

So, **explicit** final exception is only used to prevent modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Exception` of catch block is implicitly `final` that doesn't mean you can not reassign it. If you specifically make it `final` then compiler will not allow you to modify that reference. To make `throw` compile exception instance must be `final` or *effectively* `final` as already covered in linked answer.

```
public void method4() throws IOException {
    try {
        throw new IOException("1");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e = new IOException("2");// You can not modify final reference
        throw e;
    }
}
```

> *so explicit final exception is only used to prevent modify?*

Yes exactly, in case of exception, `final` modifier is redundant. It is always recommended to `throw` or `log` the exception. Modification of any exception is an *anti pattern* according to me. Generally speaking even in case of custom exception we should not modify the thrown exception unless and until you have very strong reason to do so.