# Multiple-exception catches

Tags: c#, exception

Is possible to catch more then one exception in the same `catch` block?

```
try
{   }
catch(XamlException s | ArgumentException a)
{   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once

Comment: That syntax is not part of the C# standard so you will end up with compiler errors :)

Comment: While this may not be actual code you're showing us, `ArgumentException` derives from `SystemException`, so `catch (SystemException)` is enough to ensnare both types. Of course you'd still need to cast if you wanted to inspect the argument that was incorrect, but if you need that much information, a separate `catch` block probably makes more sense anyway. Finally, you should really never be catching `ArgumentException` anyway; it means you've done something wrong, so just fix the problem rather than ignoring it.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2004/03/05/84698.aspx, to handle filters and multiple exceptions. Even if VB.NET/F# allow something like that it's a kind of trick because it's not supported directly by the CLR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If you catch a superclass, it will also catch all subclasses too:

```
try
{
    // Some code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // ...
}
```

If this catches more than you wanted then you can rethrow the exceptions that you didn't intend to catch by testing their type. If you do this, be careful to use the `throw;` syntax, and **not** `throw e;`. The latter syntax clobbers the stacktrace information.

But you can't catch two different types using the syntax you propose.

Comment: Good point on specifying between `throw;` and `throw e;`.  Just to further clarify, the reason the latter is bad is because it resets the call stack to originate from the catch block rather than from where the exception was initially thrown.  I'm sure you knew this, I just wanted to clarify for others :)

Comment: Even **throw e;** does not really work as expected. It saves the stack but it wipes the line number. For an example look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721807/using-finally-instead-of-catch/10722087#10722087) I posted here on SO.

Comment: @Adriano: Did you mean "Even `throw;`"?

Answer (score 3):

Not as succinctly as you are asking.  One way would be to catch all exceptions and handle those two specially:

```
catch(Exception e)
{   
  if((e is SystemException) || (e is ArgumentException))
     // handle, rethrow, etc.
  else
     throw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not being no C# guru however, this is standard in any oop language.

```
    try
    {
        string s = null;
        ProcessString(s);
    }
    // Most specific:
    catch (InvalidCastException e) { out_one(e); }
    catch (ArgumentNullException e) { out_two(e); }

    // Least specific - anything will get caught
    // here as all exceptions derive from this superclass
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // performance-wise, this would be better off positioned as
        // a catch block of its own, calling a function (not forking an if)
        if((e is SystemException) { out_two(); }
        else { System..... }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net, it is possible to say `Catch Ex As Exception When IsMyException(Ex)`, where `IsMyException` is any desired function which examines `Ex` and decides whether or not to catch it.  The determination of whether or not to catch `Ex` is made *before* any inner `Finally` blocks run.  Unfortunately, the makers of C# dislike the idea of allowing custom exception filters, perhaps because it would pollute the language with platform-specific details (most platforms could not support .net-style exception filters).  Consequently, the best one can hope for in C# is to do something like:

```
void HandleThisOrThatException(BaseTypeOfThisThatTheOtherException)
{ ... }

...
// Catch ThisException or ThatException, but not TheOtherException
  catch (ThisException ex) {HandleThisOrThatException(ex);}
  catch (ThatException ex) {HandleThisOrThatException(ex);}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad example because any `ArgumentException` is also a `SystemException`, so catching *all* `SystemException`s would implicitly get the `ArgumentException`s as well.

Comment: The point of catching a specific exception before the superclass exception is, you have a higher level of control. Above sample is randomly copied exception names tbh, OP asks for semantics.