# How to catch many exceptions at the same time in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, exception

```
try { 

} catch (ex: MyException1, MyException2 ) {
    logger.warn("", ex)
}
```

or

```
try { 

} catch (ex: MyException1 | MyException2 ) {
    logger.warn("", ex)
}
```

As a result, a compilation error: `Unresolved reference: MyException2`.

How can I catch many exceptions at the same time on Kotlin?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Update:
Vote for the following issue [KT-7128](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7128) if you want this feature to land in Kotlin. *Thanks @Cristan*

According to this [thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/does-kotlin-have-multi-catch/486) this feature is not supported at this moment.

> *abreslav - JetBrains Team*
>
> Not at the moment, but it is on the table

You can mimic the multi-catch though:

```
try {
    // do some work
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    when(ex) {
        is IllegalAccessException, is IndexOutOfBoundsException -> {
            // handle those above
        }
        else -> throw ex
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm copying `pdvrieze` reply here:

`This certainly works, but is slightly less efficient as the caught exception is explicit to the jvm (so a non-processed exception will not be caught and rethrown which would be the corollary of your solution)
`

Comment: this is just not the same. it will catch all exceptions, while you only want to catch certain types of exceptions with multi-catch.

Comment: @IARI The `else` clause rethrows the _unwanted_ exception.

Comment: true, i overlooked that - but its not beautiful, as I suppose it messes with the structure of the stacktrace

Comment: @IARI [The original stacktrace is preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097527/rethrowing-exceptions-in-java-without-losing-the-stack-trace)

Comment: Even if you throw away the arguments of elegance and ugliness aside,  Kotlin (which claims to be concise)  is actually 2x as verbose as Java in this case

Comment: That gets flagged by Detekt because you're catching too generic an exception ;-)

Comment: Go to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7128 to track this issue.

Comment: This is a great example where most of the people will see this answer and think it is correct because it is accepted, while correct answer is buried down and downvoted to oblivion. Correct answer is ```try{
} catch(e: MyException1){
} catch(e: MyException2) ...```.  Accepted answer catches ALL exceptions and rethrows those unprocessed. I understand you would like to do the same thing for some exceptions, but that was not even the premise of the question. It simply asks "How to catch many exceptions at the same time in Kotlin?".

Comment: @Sermilion the question includes an example with Java 7 syntax to catch multiple exceptions and handle them in the same way. Hence, the assumption that that's the intent.

Answer (score 15):

To add to [miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol)'s answer: although multi-catch in Kotlin isn't yet supported, there are more alternatives that should be mentioned.

Aside from the `try-catch-when`, you could also implement a method to mimic a multi-catch. Here's one option:

```
fun (() -> Unit).catch(vararg exceptions: KClass<out Throwable>, catchBlock: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
    try { 
        this() 
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        if (e::class in exceptions) catchBlock(e) else throw e
    }
}
```

And using it would look like:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // ...
    {
        println("Hello") // some code that could throw an exception

    }.catch(IOException::class, IllegalAccessException::class) {
        // Handle the exception
    }
}
```

You'll want to use a function to produce a lambda rather than using a raw lambda as shown above (otherwise you'll run into "MANY_LAMBDA_EXPRESSION_ARGUMENTS" and other issues pretty quickly). Something like `fun attempt(block: () -> Unit) = block` would work.

Of course, you may want to chain objects instead of lambdas for composing your logic more elegantly or to behave differently than a plain old try-catch.

**I would only recommend using this approach over [miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol)'s if you are adding some specialization**. For simple multi-catch uses, a `when` expression is the simplest solution.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you pass classes in your catch, but param `exceptions` takes objects.

Comment: you're awesome man @aro, thanks for providing this alternative

Comment: This alternative is good, thanks Aro :) Better than nothing. However, I hope they will get to that feature although my issue KT-7128 was opened 5 years ago :-)

Comment: Could you maybe change your example? I have zero clue how to call this function. I am trying `fun test() {  myExceptionCode }.catch()` but it does not work

Comment: @Andrew I'll look at changing it soon. 
It concerns me a bit that people are trying to use it raw. It's meant as a proof of concept to give people a starting point to write their own helper functions. It definitely needs to be cleaned up--mainly removing the lambda extension since that is probably a point of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The example from [aro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2832996/aro) is very good but if there are inheritances, it won't work like in Java.

Your answer inspired me to write an extension function for that. To also allow inherited classes you have to check for `instance` instead of comparing directly.

```
inline fun multiCatch(runThis: () -> Unit, catchBlock: (Throwable) -> Unit, vararg exceptions: KClass<out Throwable>) {
try {
    runThis()
} catch (exception: Exception) {
    val contains = exceptions.find {
        it.isInstance(exception)
    }
    if (contains != null) catchBlock(exception)
    else throw exception
}}
```

To see how to use, you can have a look in my library on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mark-kowalski/KotlinExtensions-Android/blob/master/kotlinsugar/src/main/java/dev/mko/kotlinsugar/KotlinSugar.kt)

Comment: What's the reason of "-1"? 

try {
   ...
} catch (X | Y e) {
  ...
}

in Java also checks the inheritance. This answer mimics the Java's behaviour, it's more convenient for example for catching IOException with many different subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can take multiple Catch and with the MultiCatch method you can detect Exceptions

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import kotlin.reflect.full.isSubclassOf

class NegetiveNumber : Exception()
class StringFalse : Exception()

fun <R> Exception.multiCatch(vararg classes: KClass<*>, block: () -> R): R {
    return if (classes.any {
            this::class.isSubclassOf(it)
        }) block()
    else throw this
}
class Human() {
    var name = ""
        set(name) {
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                throw StringFalse()
            } else {
                field = name
            }
        }
    var age = 0
        set(age) {
            if (age <= 0) {
                throw NegetiveNumber()
            } else {
                field = age
            }
        }
}
fun main() {
    val human = Human()
    human.name = "Omidreza"
    human.age = 0

    try {
        println(human.name)
        println(human.age)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
  

      e.multiCatch(NegetiveNumber::class, StringFalse::class) {
            println(e.message)
        }
    }finally {
        println("end")
    }
}
```

this is **multiCatch()**:

```
fun <R> Exception.multiCatch(vararg classes: KClass<*>, block: () -> R): R {
        return if (classes.any {
                this::class.isSubclassOf(it)
            }) block()
        else throw this
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In Kotlin you can do this:

```
try{
} catch(e: MyException1){
} catch(e: MyException2){
} catch(e: MyException3){
} [...]
```

Comment: This is obvious but it requires you to have separate catch block for each exception. However the idea of multi-catching is to have single catch block for a set of exceptions

Comment: True but it's no worse than the other answers on this question. What a massive oversight in the language.

Comment: It _is_ obviously worse because it doesn't _answer_ the question at all.

Comment: The question is "How to catch many exceptions at the same time in Kotlin?". This answers how do do that. This answer is actually is a better answer because it avoids broad exception catching like e: Exception. This is the way language designed.

Comment: @Sermilion And when I want to do the same thing for multiple exceptions, what would you like me to do? Extract a function and copy it into each catch block? Create some convoluted utility function to implement multicatch myself? Verbosely catch the base `Exception` and `when` over each type? In no way shape or form is disabling the ability to multicatch in a language that uses try-catch blocks a good design.

Comment: @joshgalva agree with the specific case where you want to do the same thing for different exceptions. Otherwise I like the Kotlin approach, it is more explicit. But my main point is that this answer is the correct one and does not deserve downvotes. The accepted answer is really bad. It catches ALL exceptions. Also,  any code analyser will complain about broadly catching exception. You should know your code, know which exceptions a function can throw and deal with them. Not just assume that you can deal with any exceptions in the same way.