Check if an object is within a list of types in Kotlin?
I want to check if the given object is within the list of types. Something like:
if(e is in listOf(FooException, BarException)) {

What is idiomatic Kotlin way to achieve this?

Is the list of types known at compile time or is it dynamic?

Are you actually thinking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760489/how-to-catch-many-exceptions-at-the-same-time-in-kotlin

I assume you mean that e is an instance of an unknown class, and you want to do something if it's specifically an instance of FooException or BarException.
If these specific classes to test for are constant, you may want to use a when statement:
when(e) {
  is FooException, is BarException -> {
    // Do something
  }
}

This generalizes well if you need to handle other possible classes in the future:
when(e) {
  is FooException, is BarException -> {
    // Do something
  }
  is BazException -> {
    // Do something else
  }
}

If that's too verbose, you can simply use if and is:
if (e is FooException || e is BarException) {
    // Do something
}

On the other hand, if you don't know at compile-time which classes to compare against, you can use lists of KClass:
val myTypes = listOf(FooException::class, BarException::class)
if (e::class in myTypes) { // Note that e cannot be nullable
    // Do something
}


The last option doesn’t handle sub typing. For example, if e is an instance of some subclass of FooException, it will fail the in condition. For that to be considered you would need reflection and use something like if (myTypes.any { e::class.isSubtypeOf(it) })
