# Is there any way to test my conversions to avoid using exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, exception

I'm constructing arbitrary objects from DataRows using Reflection, and when the rubber finally meets the road, I need to take a value from the DataRow and assign it to the property on the object.

Because DataRows can be full of types that don't support conversion, many of these result in exceptions that have to be handled. For example, DBnulls might creep up in the DataRow, or some numeric format that doesn't nicely convert to another, etc. Is there any way I can avoid throwing exceptions? (I won't accept gigantic switch statements checking for every combination of types in the target object property and source data.)

```
public void Merge(DataRow data)
{
  PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags...);
  foreach (PropertyInfo pi in props.Where(p => T_IsPrimitive(p.PropertyType)))
  {
    object src = null;
    if( dataAsDataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(pi.Name) )
       src = ((DataRow)data)[pi.Name];
    if (src != null)
    {
       if( src.GetType() != pi.PropertyType ) {
        try {
            src = Convert.ChangeType(src, pi.PropertyType);
        } catch(InvalidCastException e) {
            try { src = Convert.ChangeType(src.ToString(), pi.PropertyType); }
            catch { throw e; }
        }
       }
       pi.SetValue(this, src, null);
    }
  }
}

public bool T_IsPrimitive(Type t)
{
   return t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(Decimal) || t == typeof(String) ||
          t == typeof(DateTime) || t == typeof(TimeSpan)
}
```

So is there any way to look before I leap with these `ChangeType` conversions?

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Stecya, here's what I've come up with:

```
     if( src.GetType() != pi.PropertyType ) {
        object converted = null;
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(pi.PropertyType);
        if( converter != null ) {
           if( converter.CanConvertFrom(vType) )
              converted = converter.ConvertFrom(src);
           else if( converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(String)) )
              converted = converter.ConvertFrom(src.ToString());
        }
        src = converted;
     }
     if( src != null )
        pi.SetValue(this, src, null);
```

Logically equivalent, elegant, and no more exceptions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) to check if you can convert between types

```
bool CanConvert(Type from , Type to)
{
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(to);
    return converter != null && converter.CanConvertFrom(from);
}
```

Also you can use this TypeConverter to actually convert from one type to another

Comment: Is it guaranteed that if `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type T)` is null or `.CanConvertFrom(Type R)` is false, then Convert.ChangeType(T obj, type R) will fail? I don't want to shut down any conversions that might have otherwise worked out.

Comment: It should,but if you want to be sure than use TypeConverter to change Type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This is an elegant way of having functions do the type checking for you.

Comment: The visitor pattern does not apply. As you can see, all my conversions are to pseudo-primitive types - I cannot go in and change the code of those native types to implement a common method of converting from DataRow types.

Comment: You can add an extension method.