# Outputs are Not Filtered when one/more of the keywords it contains is/are empty

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

The function below is not working correctly at this line

```
if (itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()) ||
    itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword2.Text.ToLower()) ||
    itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword3.Text.ToLower()) ||
    itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword4.Text.ToLower()))
```

if one/more of the `txtComKeyword` is empty. It only works correctly when all four of the `txtComKeyword` are filled up.

I want to filter the XML file's data by limiting it using keywords. Which ever keywords are being detected in `<item></item>` will be shown as result. I want to allow user to choose whether to just input one/two/three/four keywords. Unfortunately, whenever there's empty `txtComKeywords`, the whole XML file's `<item></item>` will be output.

I am very very new to programming. Could you guys please help if that's possible? Thank you.

My code:

```
private void searchComByKeywords()
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

            string docPath = fileName;

            xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {

                XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement) node;

                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;

                if (itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()) || itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword2.Text.ToLower()) || itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword3.Text.ToLower()) || itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword4.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;

                    richComResults.AppendText("Author: " + itemAuthor + "\nDate: " + itemDate + "\nTitle: " + itemTitle + "\nDescription: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED:

```
private void searchComByKeywords()
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

            string docPath = fileName;

            xmlDoc.Load(docPath); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {

                XmlElement itemElement = (XmlElement) node;
                string itemDescription = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0].InnerText;
                string[] words = new String[] { null, null, null, null };
                string key1 = txtComKeyword1.Text.Trim();
                string key2 = txtComKeyword2.Text.Trim();
                string key3 = txtComKeyword3.Text.Trim();
                string key4 = txtComKeyword4.Text.Trim();
                words[0] = (key1.Length == 0 ? null : key1.ToLower());
                words[1] = (key2.Length == 0 ? null : key2.ToLower());
                words[2] = (key3.Length == 0 ? null : key3.ToLower());
                words[3] = (key4.Length == 0 ? null : key4.ToLower());

                if (words.Contains(itemDescription.ToLower())) 
                {
                    string itemTitle = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemDate = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].InnerText;
                    string itemAuthor = itemElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;

                    richComResults.AppendText("Author: " + itemAuthor + "\nDate: " + itemDate + "\nTitle: " + itemTitle + "\nDescription: " + itemDescription + "\n\n--------\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Help yourself a little. If you have a choice, stop using `XmlDocument`. Use LINQ to XML instead. Also, you'll live a happier life if you stop catching so many exceptions. Finally, if you decide you _must_ catch the exception, then display `ex.ToString()`: `Message` doesn't provide enough data.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for your precious advice. As for the exceptions part, do you mean is better not to use try-catch block? Could you please explain why? I used it because my lecturers taught us to use it, but honestly I don't really know how important and under what circumstances it must be used. I haven't learnt coding much. Thanks.

Comment: Your lecturers have taught you wrong. Only catch exceptions that you know how to handle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling+c%23?sort=faq.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you. I think I now understand what you meant after looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881473/why-catch-and-rethrow-exception-in-c. Perhaps i was wrong and not my lecturers :) Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

Read all of your words before entering the loop and save them in a string array
Before entering the word in the array check if the textbox is empty
Then use the **Array.Contains** method to check if the itemDescription is in the array of words

```
string[] words = new String[] {null, null, null, null};
// as from John Saunders comment below, 
// pass everything into a local temp variable to avoid double 
// evaluation (and string rebuild) of the Trim() method
string key1 = txtComKeyword1.Text.Trim();
string key2 = txtComKeyword2.Text.Trim();
string key3 = txtComKeyword3.Text.Trim();
string key4 = txtComKeyword4.Text.Trim();
words[0] = (key1.Length == 0 ? null : key1.ToLower());
words[1] = (key2.Length == 0 ? null : key2.ToLower());
words[2] = (key3.Length == 0 ? null : key3.ToLower());
words[3] = (key4.Length == 0 ? null : key4.ToLower());

if (words.Contains(itemDescription.ToLower())) 
    .....
```

The advantages are twofolds:

- You read the textBox and convert to lowercase just one time outside
  the loop
- The if statement is enormously simplified

The [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in C# is a simpler way to express the common coding pattern

```
if(condition == true)
   variable = first statement;
else
   variable = second statement;
```

that code becomes with the ternary operator

```
   variable = (condition == true ? first statement : second statement);
```

Comment: Thank you. but what is Dim? :| is it usable in C#?

Comment: Hi, I did this `if (txtComKeyword1.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword1.Text.ToLower()) || txtComKeyword2.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword2.Text.ToString()) || txtComKeyword3.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword3.Text.ToString()) || txtComKeyword4.Text != (String.Empty) && itemDescription.ToLower().Contains(txtComKeyword4.Text.ToString()))` and it works. :)

Comment: Sorry, Updated the answer for C#

Comment: Steve you may want to explain the ? symbol and its use to him as well he may not be familiar with the sytntax

Comment: @DJKRAZE, ok added a non very formal explanation of ternary operator. (I'm never been good to write reference text)

Comment: yea, i don't understand what is the "?" :/ i will try the code now.

Comment: The explanation looks great.. I always think of ternary as an InLine IFElse Shyuan if you can think of it that way it will make seeing the ? easier to read checks if first condition is true else use second condition..in layman terms..

Comment: Minor issue: you might want to extract `txtComKeyword1.Text.Trim()` into variables, or you're evaluating it twice.

Comment: @Steve I tried applying the above codes, but I got the red error line under the word `Contains` in this `if (words.Contains(itemDescription.ToLower())) `. May I know what's going on there? `Error: ....are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?`

Comment: That code works on net.4.0 with the System.Linq namespace. Check in the property of your project if you have marked the System.Linq namespace (Right click on Project property and go to the References page)

Comment: I have added the reference, the code seems fine. But when I click on the search button, there's nothing appear in the `richComResults`. I pasted my updated code on my initial question, can you please have a look at it?