# How do I use preprocessing directives to check if the app is being run in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, debugging, preprocessor

I need to make it possible for the users to send me back possible exception messages, which I show by wrapping the main method into try-catch, but that also forces me to see that custom message instead of visual studio's exception window.

That's why I need to make use of some preprocessing directive somehow to run the unwrapped method when in VS and wrapped when not.

Comment: why not check for an attached debugger and rethrow rather than going into your main exception handler?

Comment: I don't know how to do either yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use preprocessing directives — it can be done by checking for attached debugger in an `if` statement:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        /* application code */
    }
    else
        try
        {
            /* application code */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            // custom exception handling
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
main(){
try {
// your app code here
} 
catch (Exception ex){
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    throw;
  } else {
  // your exception handling here.
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll fix the formatting up a bit later,  but this should let you get normal exception handling (without losing the original exception stack trace), while having most exceptions in the field caught by this exception handler.

Comment: I think with this I'm actually losing the stack trace. Exception points directly to `throw`.

Comment: look at the exception details. throw by itself doesn't recreate the exception. (and you don't want to throw ex; just throw;)

Comment: So I can't actually debug as usual with this? So far in-studio and standalone application behaves as intended, except the stack trace.

Comment: Take a look over here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881473/why-catch-and-rethrow-exception-in-c

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17836/discussion-between-tetsujin-no-oni-and-user1306322)

Answer (score 0):

As Tetsujin no Oni suggested, use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`
If this boolean attribute returns true, then the Visual Studio IDE (or some other debugger!) is attached to the process, in which case - assume you're running under Visual Studio.