# Simple SQL command wont work on specific parameters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, ado.net

I have a simple SQL command that wont work in certain giving parameters.
For example if `TweetID = 59` and `UserID = 1` it will return the value;
but if `TweetID = 8` and `UserID = 1` it will not return the value.
Can some one find the reason for that?

```
public static int GetReTweetIdFromReTweetByUserIdAndTweetId(int TweetID,int UserID)
{
    string sql = "SELECT [ReTweetID] FROM [ReTweet] WHERE [TweetID] = [@TID] AND [UserID] = [@UID]";
    OleDbConnection conn = ConnectToDb();
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
    com.Parameters.Clear();
    OleDbParameter objParamater;
    objParamater = com.Parameters.Add("[@UID]", OleDbType.Integer);
    objParamater.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    objParamater.Value = UserID;
    objParamater = com.Parameters.Add("[@TID]", OleDbType.Integer);
    objParamater.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    objParamater.Value = TweetID;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int id=0;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        throw err;
    }
    finally
    {
        da.Dispose();
        dt.Dispose();
        com.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
    return id;
}
```

[image: database picture]

Comment: Off topic: look into the [using statement](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using). It could clean up your code a lot and save the hassle of calling `Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: don't `throw err` in your catch block since that resets the stacktrace. Either just do a `throw`, or get rid of the catch block altogether as you are wasting your time.

Comment: if you run the script directly against the database, does it return results?

Comment: @Sylverac Can yo explain more i really want to know what you meant.

Comment: @user1666620 I dont know why not to throw the error can you explain better? and it does get the results good.

Comment: @Rokni http://stackoverflow.com/a/881489/1666620

Comment: @Rokni Did you take a look at the link I posted? You can replace `try...catch...finally` blocks with a one-line `using` statement for instances of classes that implement the `IDisposable` interface. A `using` statement is just shorthand for a `try...catch...finally` block that calls `Dispose()` in the `finally` block for instances specified in the `using` statement. Here's the link again: http://www.dotnetperls.com/using

Comment: @Sylverac I did thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using OleDb with an Access database, parameter names are ignored.  You must supply the parameter values in the order Access expects.  If you run this query from the Access query designer ...

```sql
SELECT [ReTweetID] FROM [ReTweet] WHERE [TweetID] = [@TID] AND [UserID] = [@UID]
```

... you will see that Access asks you to supply a value for `[@TID]` first and then a value for `[@UID]`.

But in your c# code, you're supplying the parameter values in the opposite order.

However there may be something else which confuses the issue because I don't see why it succeeded with TweetID = 59 and UserID = 1.  That would only make sense to me if the table actually includes a row with TweetID = 1 and UserID = 59.  And perhaps it does.  But either way, I urge you to first supply parameter values in the order Access expects, and then see whether you need to make additional code changes.

Comment: Thank you it worked didnt know that access works that way, and i dont know also why it worked with the first parameters.

Comment: Actually Access doesn't always work that way.  For example, the parameter names are meaningful when a query is executed from DAO.  I think the parameter names are only ignored when an Access query is executed from OleDb or from ADO (which is based on OleDb).

Comment: i did use Oledb and ADO but it worked with a different set of parameters and that is weird.

Comment: Hm.  I'm surprised.  I may need to revise my thinking on this, but I'll leave that for another day.  :-)