# What is the purpose of using the following try-catch block? c#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am forever finding `try`-`catch` blocks like the following in our code:

```
public void method()
{
   try {
      //some code
   } catch(Exception ex) {
     throw ex;
   }
 }
```

What is the need for the `try`-`catch` and can someone tell me why we shouldn't do this?

Comment: This is the worst try catch pattern you can write. It does nothing except lose the stack trace when the exception bubbles up. While I can't think of any reason to do this, I suppose if you **want** to lose the stack trace this is what you would do.

Comment: See answer to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881473/why-catch-and-rethrow-an-exception-in-c

Comment: I already thought this, just wanted it confirmed that they were indeed useless

Comment: It's not useless. There are actual reasons for wanting to reset the stack trace

Comment: This code will not show you any special result. In a Multi-Layered application I doing this to pass a custom message for each type of exceptions to upper layer. in this way i can do multi-language error support and more user-friendly messages. so it's useful to formatting error messages for the end user, or Support team I think.

Comment: I assume you are throwing a custom exception within your `try` block though.