# second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous

Tags: c#

I have two async functions.

1. WriteActionToActionLog

   - documents action to log
   - add rows to db
   - async save
2. SaveSetting

   - update rows in db.
   - pulls two rows by async list
   - update them by simple logic
   - save with async.

Both are async. Wrapped with transaction. Adding both tasks to task array. Using `whenAll`.

To reduce amount of code I will write `/*logic*/`.

Meanwhile I wrote it synced, since the delay is minor, but is seems to me way more correct using parallel tasks.

tried to use `waitAll` instead of `whenAll`. but answer did not return.
tried to convert the async list within the `SaveSetting` function to synced. got the same error

.NET Framework is 4.6.1

```
public async Task<myObject> wrapperFunc(InnerServiceSettings clientSettings) {
   DbModel DB = new DbModel();  

   using (var transaction = DB.Database.BeginTransaction())
   {
      try
      {
         var tasks = new List<Task>();    

         /*logic - typeActionList created */     

         var settingsTask =  SettingsManager.SaveSetting(DB, clientSettings);
         tasks.Add(settingsTask);

         var logTask = AdminManager.WriteActionToActionLog(DB, typeActionList, clientSettings.idNum);
         tasks.Add(logTask);

         Task[] taskArr = tasks.ToArray();
         await Task.WhenAll(logTask, settingsTask); //exception thrown

         transaction.Commit();
         /*logic*/
      }
      catch(exception ex) {... rollback etc...}
   }    
}

public async static Task<bool> SaveSetting(DbModel iDb, ClientSettings iSettings)
{
   //list to be updated at db. One pull from db instead of several pulls. Also tried to made its sync, leaving save async. 
   //will return two rows from DB  
   var objListToChange = await iDb.Settings.Where(x => … ).ToListAsync();

   /*logic*/
   if (..)
   {
      var rowAtoUpdate = objListToChange.Where(x => …).FirstOrDefault();
      rowAtoUpdate.return_day = (short)iSettings.return_dayA;
   }

   if (…)
   {
      var rowBtoUpdate = objListToChange.Where(…).FirstOrDefault();
      rowBtoUpdate.return_day = (short)iSettings.return_dayB;                
   }

   try
   {
      var x = await iDb.SaveChangesAsync();
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw e;
   }
}

public async static Task<bool> WriteActionToActionLog(DbModel iDb, List<Tuple<int, int>> iActionTypeValue, int iManagerIdNum)
{    
   var ActionListToAdd = new List<ManagersActionLog>();

   foreach(var tupElem in iActionTypeValue)
   {
      ActionListToAdd.Add(new ManagersActionLog
      {
         ActionType = tupElem.Item1,
         ActionValue = tupElem.Item2,
         LogDate = DateTime.Now,
         ManagerId = iManagerIdNum,
      });
   }


   try {                   
      iDb.ManagersActionLog.AddRange(ActionListToAdd);
      var ans =  await iDb.SaveChangesAsync();
      return true;
   }
   catch(Exception ex) {
      throw ex;
   }
}
```

Once `whenAll` is reached I am getting:
A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use `await` to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: You cannot use `DbContext` concurrently like this. Either do these operation sequentially (perhaps with a single `SaveChanges` at the end) or create a new context for every operation.

Comment: Side note: You should change the way you handle exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881473/why-catch-and-rethrow-an-exception-in-c