# Error CS0103 pls Help it says The name 'currentResolutionIndex' does not exist in the current context UNITY

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioMixer audioMixer;

    public Dropdown resolutionDropdown;

    Resolution[] resolutions;

    void Start()
    {
        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;

        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolution;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions [i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if (resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }
        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();
    }

    public void SetResolution (int resolutionIndex)
    {
        Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
        Screen.SetResolution(resolution. width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
    }

    public void SetVolume (float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
    }

    public void SetQuality (int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullScreen (bool isFullScreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullScreen;
    }
}
```

pls help because the Unity Engine is making Errors that i dont understand maybe its the tutorial thats from 2017, i dont know but it would be great if you could help me. it has something to do with current Resolution Index if you need more context pls write me

Answer (score 0):

[Compiler Error CS0103](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103) is caused by using an undeclared variable or method. This issue happens where the `currentResolutionIndex` variable is never defined in the file.

```cs
void Start()
{
    /* Added the following line of code. To manage this condition when the condition is not always true, the variable must be initialized. */
    int currentResolutionIndex = -1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
    {
        /* This condition may not always be true. */
        if (resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width && resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
        {
            currentResolutionIndex = i;
        }
    }
   
    /* If the condition never works correctly, you should control and manage this condition. */
    if(currentResolutionIndex != -1)
    {
        resolutionDropdown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Exception Handling */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank so much i will see if it works

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't work! You can't use a variable without defining it because you're not coding in python.

Comment: thanks for the help but, i am a beginner and i dont know how to control and manage the exeption

Comment: Nevermind i solved it. YOU ARE A HERO

Comment: If you are a new user then read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881473/why-catch-and-rethrow-an-exception-in-c) to learn exception handling in C#.