# Imitation of OperationCanceledException scenario with unit-test fails

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I use Moq 4.18.2 framework for my tests.

The `RtspClient` might throw an `OperationCanceledException` from `ConnectAsync`. So, I try to test this scenario. My test below throws an exception `System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.` and the `catch (OperationCanceledException)` never gets executed. What am I doing wrong here?

**RTSP**

```
public interface IRtspClient : IDisposable
{
    event EventHandler<RawFrame> FrameReceived;

    Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token);
    Task ReceiveAsync(CancellationToken token);
}
```

**Method that uses IRtspClient**

```
public async Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    try
    {
        await _rtspClient.ConnectAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        OnConnected();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        OnConnectAttemptCanceled(ex);
        throw;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        OnFailedToConnect(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ConnectAsync_Canceled()
{
    var expectedCanceledTaskStatus = true;

    var tcs = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tcs.Cancel();
    var rtspClient = new Mock<IRtspClient>();
    rtspClient
        .Setup(_ => _.ConnectAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromException<OperationCanceledException>(new OperationCanceledException()))

    var actualCanceledTaskStatus = false;
    var camera = new MyCamera(rtspClient.Object);
    camera.FailedToConnect += () => actualCanceledTaskStatus = true;
    await camera.ConnectAsync(tcs.Token);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCanceledTaskStatus, actualCanceledTaskStatus);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Added missing `await` as suggested by @Dai, but my test still fails. Can anyone take a look at the test code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake (in addition to what @Dai noticed). I should have either put `await camera.ConnectAsync` from my test in `try-catch` or used `Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync`. I chose the latter. Here is the working test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ConnectAsync_Canceled()
{
    var expectedTaskCanceledStatus = true;

    var rtspClient = new Mock<IRtspClient>();
    rtspClient
        .Setup(_ => _.ConnectAsync(default(CancellationToken)))
        .Returns(Task.FromException(new OperationCanceledException()));

    var actualTaskCanceledStatus = false;
    var camera = new MyCamera(rtspClient.Object);
    camera.ConnectAttemptCanceled += () => actualTaskCanceledStatus = true;

    await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<OperationCanceledException>(async () => await camera.ConnectAsync());
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedTaskCanceledStatus, actualTaskCanceledStatus);
}
```

Comment: Don't you have Code Analysis on? There's a warning on by default that's raised whenever a `Task` is left abandoned without being `await`'d.

Comment: @Dai, I probably didn't notice. I want to accept your answer since it helped me to find my bug. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: May I enquire as to how you have 13.000+ karma on StackOverflow... yet you're asking how to accept an answer?

Comment: No. To be fair - your answer didn't solve my issue. It helped me to find the real bug in my test, which I described in my posted answer. So, since yours and my answers make 100% together, I wonder what should I do? I've never been in this situation. Should I select your answer or mine?

Comment: Ah, a simple misundrestanding on my part :) - I thought you _literally_ meant that you didn't know how to click the green checkmark, lol

Answer (score 2):

- You need to `await` the returned `Task` *inside* the `try{}` block - otherwise
  synchronous control will immediately leave the `try{}` block.
- Exceptions thrown inside an anonymous function (or local function, or lambda method, or *ye olde school* `delegate()` local) will not be caught by the `catch`.
- Also, `CancellationTokenSource` is `IDisposable`, so you should change your `ConnectAsync_Canceled` test to wrap it in a `using()` block.
- Also, *don't swallow exceptions* - so my code below captures both exceptions for possible investigation and re-throws them with `throw;` ([don't use `throw ex;`: it resets the recorded stack-trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881489/159145); instead just do `throw;` by itself).

  - With `OperationCanceledException` and/or `TaskCanceledException` specifically, the exception needs to be re-thrown right back to the original caller (i.e. the owner of the `CancellationTokenSource`); whereas if a `TaskCanceledException` is caught and handled without the corresponding `Task` "seeing" then the caller will assume the operation succeeded *despite* the cancelation request.

Change your code to this:

```cs
public async Task ConnectAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
{
    try
    {
         await this.rtspClient.ConnectAsync(cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);

         this.OnConnected();
    }
    catch( OperationCanceledException cEx )
    {
        this.OnConnectAttemptCanceled( cEx );

        throw; // Re-throw so the `Task` representing *this method* (`ConnectAsync`) will report as Cancelled rather than Succeeded.
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) 
    {
        this.OnFailedToConnect( ex );

        throw; // Re-throw so the `Task` representing *this method* (`ConnectAsync`) will report as Failed rather than Succeeded.
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right I forgot the await. Can you take a look at the test too?

Comment: @theateist I did look at your test code when I wrote my answer but I don't know enough about your test code to say anything useful at this point.

Comment: I've updated my post. What additional information do you need to find the issue with my test?

Comment: Well, for example, I have no idea what `Mock<IRtspClient>()` does.

Comment: I found my mistake in the test. I added the in my answer that I posted.